# RabbitMq C API : emulating "rabbitmqctl cluster_status -n rabbit@<remote hostname>" from C API

Tags: c, rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl, rabbitmq-c

I'm trying to get the list of nodes in a cluster using only the C API.

More or less what the following shell command returns, but from C API

```
rabbitmqctl cluster_status -n rabbit@<remote hostname>
```

I'd like to avoid calling `rabbitmqctl` from the C with `system()` or `popoen()` or whatever as I want to avoid having a dependency on the rabbitmq server package on the client side.

Any hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting RabbitMQ cluster status is not something from AMQP standard and it's not something that `rabbitmq-c` supports, at least at this time. There is [Management Plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) that provides RabbitMQ HTTP API, which is the closest thing you want.

Have a look on  [RabbitMQ HTTP API client for Ruby](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/rabbitmq_http_api_client)  readme file, which covers getting cluster status from HTTP API.

Comment: Don't you mean " _... and it's_ not _something rabbitmq-c supports ..._ " ?  And many thanks for your answer and hints

Comment: Sure, *it's NOT something that rabbitmq-c supports*. You are welcome.